# xcrun can't find Xcode path

Tags: xcode, command-line, xcrun

Mac OS X 10.8.2
Xcode 4.5.2 (installed at /Applications/Xcode.app)

Tried
`xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app`
After that
`xcode-select -print-path`
outputs correct path (/Applications/Xcode.app). But
`xcrun -find gcc`
fails with error
xcrun: Error: could not stat active Xcode path '/Developer/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer'. (No such file or directory).

**Update 1:**
Here are permission specifiers

```
ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app
```

total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 my  admin  544 Oct 30 23:38 Contents

```
ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents
```

total 24
drwxr-xr-x@  8 my  admin    272 Oct 30 23:30 Applications
drwxr-xr-x@  9 my  admin    306 Oct 30 23:36 Developer
drwxr-xr-x@  5 my  admin    170 Oct 30 23:30 Frameworks
-rw-r--r--@  1 my  admin  15289 Oct 19 14:22 Info.plist
drwxr-xr-x@  3 my  admin    102 Aug  5 08:03 Library
drwxr-xr-x@  3 my  admin    102 Oct 30 23:10 MacOS
drwxr-xr-x@ 16 my  admin    544 Oct 30 23:37 OtherFrameworks
-rw-r--r--@  1 my  admin      8 Oct 19 14:22 PkgInfo
drwxr-xr-x@ 56 my  admin   1904 Oct 30 23:36 PlugIns
drwxr-xr-x@ 52 my  admin   1768 Oct 30 23:46 Resources
drwxr-xr-x@ 17 my  admin    578 Oct 30 23:46 SharedFrameworks
drwxr-xr-x@  4 my  admin    136 Oct 17 21:50 XPCServices
drwxr-xr-x@  3 my  admin    102 Oct 30 23:10 _CodeSignature
-rw-r--r--@  1 my  admin    523 Oct 30 23:10 version.plist

```
ls -l /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

total 0
drwxr-xr-x@  3 my  admin  102 Aug  5 07:29 Documentation
drwxr-xr-x@  7 my  admin  238 Dec 20 21:09 Library
drwxr-xr-x@  7 my  admin  238 Oct 30 23:46 Makefiles
drwxr-xr-x@  5 my  admin  170 Oct 30 23:28 Platforms
drwxr-xr-x@  3 my  admin  102 Oct 10 01:37 Toolchains
drwxr-xr-x@ 22 my  admin  748 Oct 30 23:31 Tools
drwxr-xr-x@  7 my  admin  238 Oct 30 23:46 usr
Please help.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Fixed! In terminal:

```
$ DEVELOPER_DIR="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/"  
$ export DEVELOPER_DIR
```

Explanation:
While reading `man xcrun` I noticed that there is DEVELOPER_DIR environment variable that takes precedence of xcode-select. So here we are setting that variable to correct path.

Comment: This answer is probably not idea since xcode-select should be able to configure the path automatically without the need for maintaining an extra environment variable. See answer from @Nanda

Comment: Just to clarify, you can just do this: ```xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/``` without having to specify environment variable.

Comment: Great its Working fine for me.!

Answer (score 17):

Run this to set your Developer folder:

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```

Comment: Thanks, worked for me! Exporting only the path wasn't successful.

Answer (score 14):

Open Xcode > Preferences > Locations > Select your Xcode version from the dropdown and exit Xcode [ref](http://theredfoxfire.github.io/2016-03-03-react-native-failed-build.html)

Comment: That was really easy! Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### Do the following steps

Open Xcode

Preferences->Locations->Command Line Tools-> Select Xcode Version

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all the possible options:

- Re-installing Xcode
- Changed all sort of paths
- re-installed developer tools
- I even re-installed the operating system!

Downloading the latest GIT version from [Here](http://git-scm.com/download/mac) did the trick though.

I believe it's an error from upgrading the operating system. I think a clean/format reinstall would have fixed it as well (since all the settings are being kept)

Please note: Restart the current Terminal window & This is not a temporary solution.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line to '~/.bashrc' file:

```
export DEVELOPER_DIR=”/Applications/XCode.app/Contents/Developer”
```

run `source ~/.bashrc` , and restart terminal.

Answer (score 0):

> sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/Xcode.app

Worked in my case.