# Issue with gcc on mac in setting Ror environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gcc

I am following this link : http://railsapps.github.io/installrubyonrails-mac.html
to set up my ROR environment, I have successfully upgraded to MacOS Sierra and also installed Xcode with command line tools but unfortunately when I type gcc in terminal I get the following result

```
Alis-MacBook-Pro:~ aliahmad$ gcc
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path 
  (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at:       
   /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
```

I don't know what does it mean can someone please assist me to sort it out it will be so helpful for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Invalid active developer path on MAC OS X after installing Ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706428/invalid-active-developer-path-on-mac-os-x-after-installing-ruby)

Comment: how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There is [this](http://tips.tutorialhorizon.com/2015/10/01/xcrun-error-invalid-active-developer-path-library-developer-commandline-tools-missing-xcrun/) blog which have solution for the same problem.

Run the following command

```
xcode-select --install
```

Comment: i already did it but result is same and now i am trying to download Xcode from appstore. Hope it might resolve the issue but still don't know i am following the right path or not