# PIP Install web3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, ethereum, web3py

I am having trouble installing web3.py on my macOS by pip

The error I am getting is

> xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun

I have followed the docs and make a venv they way the said and still no luck I am using python 3.6.6

https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/troubleshooting.html#setup-environment

Has anyone else had this problem?

Comment: Have you tried following the advice here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706428/invalid-active-developer-path-on-mac-os-x-after-installing-ruby

Comment: xcode-select --install Has solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading your Python version to the latest one available. Download the newest version of it from [www.python.org](https://www.python.org/) or from your package manager of choice.

If you are using home brew just type:

```
brew update 

brew upgrade python3
```

Then just simple use pip to install the required packages.

```
pip install web3
```

Comment: xcode-select --install solved my problem thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

you need to use another command also, it'll help to clear the user error on your os.

```
xcode-select --install
```