# accidentally deleted some packages from R studio and now can't Redownload

Tags: r

When I try to redownload packages like digest I get this error. 
installing the source package ‘digest’

```
trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/digest_0.6.23.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 143316 bytes (139 KB)

downloaded 139 KB

installing *source* package ‘digest’ ...
package ‘digest’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
using staged installation
libs
xcrun: error: invalid active developer path (/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools), missing xcrun at: /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/xcrun
ERROR: compilation failed for package ‘digest’
removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/digest’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘digest’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
    ‘/private/var/folders/rn/2fyqm2wd6qs5pq5ttswtffvh0000gn/T/Rtmpv0Vy8N/downloaded_packages’
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Do you have write access?!

Comment: How about this solution, does it work? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28706428/invalid-active-developer-path-on-mac-os-x-after-installing-ruby?