# Xamarin: NSInvalidReceivePortException: connection went invalid while waiting for a reply because a mach port died

Tags: xcode, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin-studio, xamarin.mac

I'm getting the following error when I create Xamarin form application.

```
"NSInvalidReceivePortException: connection went invalid 
while waiting for a reply because a mach port died"
```

I've Xcode-beta 8 SDK installed. I've also change the Xcode path in Xamarin Studio -> Preferences

Console shows the following in error report. Can anyone please advice?

```
Process:               csproxy [603]
Path:                  /Applications/Xamarin Studio.app/Contents/Resources/lib/monodevelop/AddIns/MonoDevelop.IPhone/csproxy
Identifier:            csproxy
Version:               0
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           csproxy [603]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-06-15 08:55:22.985 +0530
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.5 (15F34)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        90E52BD1-8ACB-0BA4-AF8A-6A44608345E2


Time Awake Since Boot: 3200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Application Specific Information:
Assertion failed: ((path != nil) && "Unable to determine path to Xcode.app"), function ___xcodeAppPath_block_invoke, file /BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/CoreSimulator/CoreSimulator-260.5/CoreSimulator/find_xcode.m, line 117.


Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution in this post. [xcrun can't find Xcode path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14334708/xcrun-cant-find-xcode-path)

Since I downloaded Xcode beta, I guess path wasn't set.

```
sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -switch /Users/apple/Downloads/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
```